# string matching in prototypejs

Tags: javascript, string, prototypejs

I have following string in javascript.

```
str = '<a href="/display/1">This is link</a>';
```

I want to get `"This is link"` from above string but not succeeded.

I tried this also

```
str.innerHTML
```

but getting **undefined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string is not a DOM object. 
The variable you have - `str` is a string, the innerHTML property only exists on DOM (Document Object Model) nodes, so you'll have to convert to that first to use this approach.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str;
var domNode = div.firstChild;

var textYouWant = domNode.innerHTML;
```

---

Or with jQuery

```
$(str).html();
```

Comment: oh ok. so this answer is in pure javascript ?

Comment: yep, no frameworks here, though it is simpler in jQuery - `$(str).html()`  (sorry, not a prototype user)

Comment: looks like the Element class is your friend in prototype though - http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/new/

Answer (score 3):

In PrototypeJS, you can use the [`stripTags()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/String/prototype/stripTags/) function:

```
'a <a href="#">link</a>'.stripTags();
 // -> 'a link'
 'a <a href="#">link</a><script>alert("hello world!");</script>'.stripTags();
// -> 'a linkalert("hello world!");'
 'a <a href="#">link</a><script>alert("hello world!");</script>'.stripScripts().stripTags();
// -> 'a link'
```

Answer (score 0):

Prototype's `stripTags()` will do the job but depending on your requirements you may not want to actually strip out all the HTML tags. If for example you have a  tag inside your  tag, `stripTags()` will remove that too. Here's how you'd do it in plain JavaScript using a regular expression:

```
function textFromLink(linkText) {
    return linkText.replace(/.*<a[^>]*>\s*(.+)\s*<\/a>.*/, '$1');
}
```

The above function will return the content of the  tag, trimmed of whitespace, without touching other tags inside the  tag.